# Relation to many and get without this

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

```
User:
id | name
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
5  | five


House:
id | name
1  | London
2  | Barcelona

UserHouse:
id_user | id_house
 1      |  1
 2      |  2
 4      |  1


$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('User u')
   // many selectors here
  ->leftJoin('u.UserHouse uh')
  ->addWhere('????????');

$users = $q->execute();
```

I would like get all user without House (that is - not in table UserHouse) - this should return me user 3 and 5.

I know, i can use:

```
->from('UserHouse uh')
```

and next relation to User but i must have and use:

```
  ->from('User u')
```

because i use this query with many selectors - can't edit this. I must started with       **->from('User u')**

So what i must fill in *->addWhere('????????')* that this return me users without house?

If not with Doctrine, how can i get this with simply SQL?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  In any case, this is basically an `EXCEPTION JOIN` type query - there's a number of examples on here for mySQL; most of them involve checking if some attribute of the `LEFT JOIN`-table is `NULL`... Don't know how that translates to Doctrine, though ('uh IS NULL' ?).

Comment: @X-Zero please add new answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, this type of query needs what is known as an `EXCEPTION JOIN`.  Some RDBMSs actually implement this as a separate type (such as DB2), while others need to use a workaround.  In your case, it amounts to (in SQL):

```
SELECT User.* 
FROM User
LEFT JOIN UserHouse
ON UserHouse.id_user = User.id
WHERE UserHouse.id_user IS NULL
```

Which [will yield](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4aa0/1) the expected 'not in a house' records.

There are similar examples in a number of places on this site.

I've never used Doctrine, so I can't help you there.  But my best guess would be something like:

```
addWhere('uh IS NULL')
```

or

```
addWhere('uh.id_user IS NULL')
```